# Why does TypeScript throw error when using type unions in type declarations?

Tags: typescript, union, declaration

I am trying to write type declarations for the simple npm package [merge-ranges](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-ranges)

I have come up with the following:

```
type rangeElement = number | Date;
type range = [rangeElement, rangeElement];

declare module "merge-ranges" {
  declare function mergeRanges(ranges: range[]): range[];
  export default mergeRanges;
}
```

However, when testing with Date, ranges typescript throws an error saying `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Date'.` and when testing with number ranges, the error is `Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'number'.`

Comment: Can you show a function call that fails type check?

Comment: Could you give an example where it fails?

Comment: The code you posted does not produce any error. Please edit to make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is not sound from types perspective. Type definition:

```ts
...(range: [(number | Date), (number | Date)][])...
```

is allowing clearly wrong combinations for elements. `[1, new Date()]` for example is totally valid value of this type.

What you really need is to make argument to be typed either `[number, number][]` or `[Date, Date][]`. And add [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) for the result to be typed correctly:

```ts
declare function mergeRanges(ranges: [number, number][]): [number, number][]
declare function mergeRanges(ranges: [Date, Date][]): [Date, Date][]
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WoqjPN)